# Visual Studio не даёт нужные подсказки

Tags: visual-studio

Когда установил Visual Studio подсказки работали корректно. Но после отката системы к точке восстановления созданной до установки VS половина файлов VS просто удалилась.
Пришлось переустанавливать Visual Studio, и начались странности с подсказками. Они вообще не совпадают с тем что пишу.

Пробовал удалять через установщик, плюс вручную удалял папки в AppData и Progra Files. Всё то же самое.
Переустановил систему. Visual Studio похоже подтянуло настройки из интернета, ведь подсказки всё ещё странно работают.
Пробовал Средства->Импорт и экспорт параметров->Сбросить все параметры. Не то.

На снимке экрана должно быть видно что весь текст выделен жирным зеленым цветом, и хотя я пишу Float мне в подсказки идут abstract/class/delegate.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: При создании нового проекта все норм? это пробовал https://stackoverflow.com/a/38421156/407561?

Comment: NMD, при создании нового проекта всё так же. Хотя старый проект вроде нормально подсказки даёт. 
Удалять ту папку пробовал, всё так же не полноценные подсказки.